# Max value: Max of a given column in the cvs file

Tags: hadoop

Input: file1: input job should take input as below file.
C1 - ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL.
C2 -  10,15,20,30.
C3 - B1,B2,B3,B4.
C4 - 5,2,6,9.

Input parameter: column no ( ex.2).

Comment: Can u give what the code to write...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming Q+A site for specific programming questions, not a code writing service. We require that posters first attempt the problem themselves. We are then more than happy to help with specific problems you have with your code.